# writing a PNG in grayscale or RGB in C with libpng

Tags: c, image-processing, rgb, grayscale, libpng

I'm trying to write a PNG file from an image that can be grayscale (8bits*1componant) or rgb (8bits*3componants) with `libpng` in `C`.

I read the manual and wrote this piece of code that doesn't work :-/

```
/* writing the image */
png_byte *row_pointers[img->height];
int h;
for (h = 0 ; h < img->height ; h++)
{
    row_pointers[h] = img->data+h*img->width*image_components;
}
png_write_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);
```

Nothing is written into the image, and I don't understand why.

`img.data` points to the image datas (interlaced in the case of RGB format)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says you are supposed to use png_write_end, see "Finishing a sequential write" section in http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html.
There are plenty of examples out there (eg http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html)

Comment: when I use it, in addition to the empty png file, I have this error `libpng error: No IDATs written into file`

Comment: What if you use directly: 
    png_write_png (png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);
 instead? It works for me and I was able to replicate your error when using png_write_image, then png_write_end. However the example I use also runs other functions before (eg creating the info_ptr content, png_set_IHDR, ...).